# why my training and validation loss curve looks like lognormal distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, training

I trained an XGBoost model and my training and validation curve looks like this? Is something weird I am doing? I have always seen it going from high to low or like a U-shape incase of overfitting. How come the model is better without any training (at iteration=0)?

[image]

Comment: I think it would be really weird if these were curves for learning and testing :)

Comment: From the curve it seems that initially the model is good (since the loss at the first iteration is similar to last iteration loss) - you should also check if a value of almost 0.02 is really a good loss value - and then it diverges a bit, next stabilizing quite slowly. Maybe the model is learning too fast, so it's a bit unstable during training. My suggestion is to tune the hyper-parameters